# Is there any function i can use to compare year in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to figure out a way where I can check if my record in database was created in a different year by using the created_at column. The condition is like this. If I bought a phone this year which is 2022, then I can only purchase a new phone in the next year which is 2023. If possible, I want the result to be in boolean because Im going to use it inside an if else condition.I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: You need to import `use \Carbon\Carbon;` and use  as `Carbon::parse($yourModel->created_at)->year`. Also, please search here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare+year+laravel OR https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+compare+laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can explore using Carbon, which I believe is used in Laravel as well.

An example here (you should customise to your need):

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

$phoneRecord = Model::query()->find(...);
$phoneBuyDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $phoneRecord->created_at);
$canBuyPhone = $phoneBuyDate->copy()->addYear(1)->isSameYear(Carbon::now());
```

More details here:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Hii ^^ thank u so much!! this one works for my case but I made some adjustment to the code. I also came up with another alternative cause I read about diffInYears() function in the carbon docs u shared above. It is what I actually needed. Thank u again for helping me out ^^

Answer (score 0):

**whereYear()**

whereYear() will help to get only specific year records from your timestamps fields. you can see bellow example.

```
    $products = DB::table('products')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '2016')
            ->get();
dd($products);
```

Comment: Im sorry but whereYear() is used for querying and for my case i dont think this is what I actually need. Anyway thank u for helping ^^